# Remote will not always unlock car plus cannot insert key into ignition?

Tags: chevrolet, cobalt

Remote will not always lock & unlock car doors + key will not turn in power ignition.
I did have it changed twice plus replaced remote battery twice
06

Comment: What was changed twice?  You can't insert or turn the key in the ignition?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the RF receiver of the central locking system is faulty. It was not the problem with the Car Battery or the remote battery.

---

Take it to the service station and get it repaired.